# Prefix and suffix for parameters using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

## Problem

I am trying to get CSS colours highlighted and suggested as if I was editing a CSS file in IntelliJ IDEA.

```
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language

fun x() {
    c("red")
}

fun c(
    @Language(
            value  = "CSS",
            prefix = "*{background:",
            suffix = "}")
    text: String): String = text
```

if I manually add the suffix and prefix like this:

```
c("*{background: red}")
```

then I get the expected highlighting and suggestions.

## Expected Outcome

I expect the parameter to be treated as it had the prefix before it and the suffix after it, as [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html#injection_prefix_and_suffix) suggest.

## Actual Outcome

The prefix and suffix appear to be ignored

## IDEA version

2018.1.1 EAP (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Seems like something better to be addressed to the Jetbrains' bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: In addition: check the file type association. IntelliJ won't recognise language features if it's not associated with that particular language.